# creating python script which use libssh2 to access remote servers

Tags: python, libssh2

creating python script which use libssh2 to access remote servers- I want to make python script that accesses a remote server which further access another server in the same session.This should return a channel to the host comp.I want to then execute the commands in this channel say for e.g. access database.I have tried it with libssh2 library but got stuck.Can somebody help me with this, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The de facto Python module for SSH2 is [paramiko](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/paramiko/1.9.0), which does not use libssh2.

Answer (score 0):

There's a [python binding for libssh2](http://www.no-ack.org/2010/11/python-bindings-for-libssh2.html) already. Perhaps it can make your task easier...

Answer (score 0):

Libssh2 with Python bindings is much faster than Paramiko.

Python binding: https://pypi.org/project/ssh2-python/
API: https://pypi.org/project/ssh2-python/

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import socket
import os
import time

from ssh2.session import Session  #@UnresolvedImport in eclipse

class ssh_session:
    def __init__(self,user, password, host = "localhost",port=22):
        sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        sock.connect((host, port))
        self.s = Session()
        self.s.handshake(sock)
        self.s.userauth_password(user, password)        
        self.chan = self.s.open_session()
        self.chan.shell()
        self.s.set_blocking(False)  #switch to non-blocking
        self.received_bytes=0

    def read(self,minwait=0.01):   #10 ms wait are enough for localhost  
        buf = b""                  #when you send simple commands
        startread=time.time()
        while True:
            size, data = self.chan.read()
            if size > 0: 
                buf+=data
                self.received_bytes+=size
                time.sleep(0.01)
            if minwait > 0:  # if we have a larger minwait than wait
                timedelta = time.time()-startread
                if timedelta > minwait: 
                    break    
            else:
                break  # non-blocking return with zero minwait
            #repeat the while loop until minwait       
        return (buf.decode())      
                     
    def write(self,cmd):
        self.chan.write(cmd+"\n")       

user="<user>"
passwd="<pass>"
contime = time.time()    
timedelta = 0            
con1 = ssh_session(user,passwd)   #create connection instance

#skip banner aka os welcome message
#banner should be done after 1 second or more than 200 received Bytes
while timedelta < 1 and con1.received_bytes < 200:
    timedelta = time.time() - contime
    con1.read()   #just read but do not print
      
#send command to host
con1.write("pwd")
#receive answer, on localhost connection takes just about 0.3ms
print (con1.read())   #you can pass a minimum wait time in seconds here
                      #e.g. con1.read(0.8) # wait 0.8 seconds
```